# How flutter MethodChannel call simultaneously?

Tags: flutter

I use MethodChannel to communicate between native and flutter.

```
private func methodA() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) { [weak self] in
            self?.channel?.invokeMethod("methodA", arguments: nil) { result in
            }
        }
}
private func methodB() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) { [weak self] in
            self?.channel?.invokeMethod("methodB", arguments: nil) { result in
            }
        }
}
```

Then I call simultaneously like

```swift
methodA()
methodB()
```

In flutter

```dart
//main.dart
channel.setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) async {
    if (call.method == 'methodA') {
      debugPrint("methodA------");
      final items = await dbHelper.items();
      return json.encode(items);
    } else if (call.method == 'methodB') {
      debugPrint("methodB------");
      final list = await dbHelper.list();
      return json.encode(list);
    }
  });

  runApp(MyApp());
```

But it always call **methodB** only!

The call is async, right? Why this happens? How can I to fix this?

Comment: This might be a concurrency issue what happens if you add a different delay so the calls are not simultaneous

Comment: Did you notice the missing close quote here? `'methodA) {`

Comment: @ahmetakil I added another second delay but the result is same

Comment: @RichardHeap thx buddy, fixed